# jQuery UI resizable containment not responding to newly created element

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-ui-draggable, jquery-ui-resizable

I am using the jQuery UI resizable and draggable functions. First I create a new element, append it to the `body` and set the containments

```
function setDraggable(){
    $div = $(document.createElement('div')).css({
        //blah blah (tested and working perfectly)
    });
    $('body').append($div);
    $('div#dragBox'). draggable({
            containment : $div
    }). resizable({
            containment : $div
    })
}
```

It works for the `draggable` but not for the `resizable`

Answer (score 0):

Here you go with the solution https://jsfiddle.net/wx4r7kz6/

```js
setDraggable = function(){
    $div = $(document.createElement('div')).css({
        //blah blah (tested and working perfectly)
        'width': '100px',
        'height': '100px',
        'display': 'inline-block',
      'border': '1px solid'
    });
    $div.attr("id", "dragBox");
    $('body').append($div);
    $('div#dragBox').draggable().resizable();
}

setDraggable();
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```